# Angular python-shell fails on first line

Tags: python, angular, npm

**Set Up**

I am having an odd problem.
I have a website and I am hoping to run a python script when someone presses a button.

So, I have followed this tutorial: https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell

**Question:**

My console prints this: `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

on this line: `var PythonShell = require('python-shell');`

This is the first line in my .js function. I added this line after the `npm install` step.

How do I overcome this error?

**Potentially Helpful Notes**

My script looks like this:

```
angular.module('MYApp')
    .controller('MyTypeController', function ($scope, $http, $stateParams, $state) {


        $scope.runPythonRoutine = function () {
            console.log("Error 1");
            var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

            var myshell = new PythonShell.run('hello.py', function (err, results) {
              console.log("Error 2");

              // script finished
            });

        };

...
```

My package.json contains:

```
...
"node-uuid": "1.4.7",
"python-shell": "^0.5.0",
...
```

Comment: But this appears to be inside Angular code, ie on the browser side. NodeJS runs on the server side.

Comment: you are correct, i got my words wrong, will fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require() does not exist in the browser/client-side JavaScript. You need [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/optimization.html#download) to use require() in the browser. You must also add this to package.json:

```
"require.js": "version"
```

and specify require.js in the `<script>` tag of the html code at the bottom, like so:

```
<script src="/location/of/require.js/"></script>
```